# Linker SDK Only - Deserializing read-only members to ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail

Tags: android, wcf, xamarin, sdk, linker

First, sorry for my english

Today, I'm in front of an impossible problem...

I have an application in 2 parts :

1. Application in Xamarin Android
2. PCL (I use a PCL because the app need to call a WebService in WCF)

In release, with Linker set to none, the app work like a charm but when I want to set the value to SDK Only (for reduce APK size). I got an error (See below)

Part of Stack trace :

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Error on deserializing read-only members in the class: 
No set method for property 'Message' in type 'System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail'.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object:__icall_wrapper_mono_delegate_end_invoke (object,intptr)
  at (wrapper delegate-end-invoke) <Module>:end_invoke_object__this___object[]&_IAsyncResult (object[]&,System.IAsyncResult)
```

The error raise in the AsyncCompletedEventArgs of the PCL's call

I think, I need to create an "linkDescrption" file like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<linker>
  <assembly fullname="System.ServiceModel">
    <type fullname="System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail" preserve="fields">
      <field name="Message" />
    </type>
  </assembly>
</linker>
```

But i don't know what I need to put in this file..

System information :

- VisualStudio : 2013
- Xamarin Plugin : Last stable version
- JDK : 1.8.0_102
- Android : 4.4 (Kit kat)

Can you help me ? If information is missing, tell me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already close to the solution - actually, I think your linker config file should work. You'll have to set its build action to "LinkDescription".

However, your approach is very granular. I'd probably try to prevent linking for the entire assembly and see if the APK size is already small enough for your requirement. You could use the `<AndroidLinkSkip/>` [element](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/#linkskip) in the Android project's CSPROJ file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<AndroidLinkSkip>System.ServiceModel;System.Runtime.Serialization</AndroidLinkSkip>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Please note that in the example above I also included `System.Runtime.Serialization` because it can also cause you problems. Feel free to remove and try without.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/build_process/

Comment: Before, I come i have found the solution ! But Thank you so much ! Great reactive and help ! 

Finally, In csproj properties => Android Options => Linker, I have set linker to "SDK Assembly Only" and (just below) Skip linking assemblies to "System.ServiceModel" . Just this .DLL is enought !

Again Thanks !